# How to change the Top Navigation Background color in mobile

Tags: css, mobile

Looking to change the background color of the navigation to black while viewing in mobile. Would then like to change the "menu " text to white so that you can see the text. Thanks for the help. I can't find the right css selectors to target this.

[www.jobspark.ca](http://www.jobspark.ca)

#### UPDATED

```
@media all and (max-width: 640px) {
.top-nav {
 background: #000 !important;
 color: #fff !important;
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved it:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .mobile-nav .show-nav {
        display: block;
        padding: 1em 40px;
        color: #fff;
        background: #000; 
        cursor: pointer;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should solve the issue, but you should notice that the screen width should not be more than 940px. The 940px to ensure that it will work with almost any mobile.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 940px) { 
     .top-nav {
         background: #000 !important;
         color: #fff !important;
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target a specific viewport width through a media query in your css:

```
@media all and (max-width: 400px) {
  .top-nav {
     background-color: black;
     color: white;
  }
}
```

This is the only way using css, you can not target a specific device (mobile, tablet) but rather target some specific attribute of that device (in this case, the width or the screen).

You can googling for 'media queries' or 'responsive design' to find deeper examples.

Comment: @media (max-width: 640px) {
    .top-nav {
     background: #000!important;
     color: #fff !important;                                        Didnt quite seem to work but I think we are on the right track
     }
     }

Comment: @ChrisS edited, but is just an example, fit it to your specific needs

Comment: I have no idea why it is not working. Ive played around with it for a while and still nothing. I put the code up above

Comment: Please provide more feedback. What browser or mobile device are you using to test? Can you see in Firebug what styles are applied to .top-nav?

Answer (score 0):

You first issue is that there is no element on your page with a class of `.top-nav`. You might mean `.nav`. However, there are many more problems there than just the background color. You need to set a lot more styles for the navigation on small screens for it to show up.

On your desktop browser (like Chrome) narrow the browser right down and right click on the menu to Inspect Element. You can see all the styles that apply to the menu at that width, and then go about setting styes for the menu.

Comment: Thanks for looking at things. I was able to figure out the styling just need to figure out a way to insert the logo into the navigation somehow. I am trying to get rid of the + and switch it with the logo